# Married to an Italian citizen, but I need to go to Germany alone, do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, overstaying, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

I am a South Korean, married to an Italian woman. Currently, I ran out of visa (the tourist visa) and I had no time to redo the marriage visa. So I am currently overstaying with a tourist visa for about a year and a half now.

Soon I have to visit my friend in Germany, but my wife is busy with work, and may not be able to join me on this trip to Germany. Will I have any problems going through the passport control in Italy, and passport control in going into Germany?

I do have the documents to prove that I am married.
So will I have any problems if I do travel to Germany alone at the passport controls?

or will they just let me pass through?

Comment: If you are travelling from Italy to Germany, there will be no 'passport controls'.

Comment: @GayotFow not fully exact. There is Switzerland between Germany and Italy, and they still do controls at their border from time to time. But depending where the person goes, one could avoid Switzerland. Anyway, within Schengen there could be documents control at any place, not limited to borders. This risk is relatively low (and that was probably your point) but it does not mean that there could not be troubles.

Comment: Do you have your carta di soggiorno?

Comment: No i do not have any cara di soggiorno.

Comment: As another person noted below, you should first get one of those. Since you are married to an EU national, you do qualify, and it proves your right of residence in the EU.

Comment: The only reasons i couldnt get the visa was because I do not have a residence that is in my name currently.

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you please tell me how can i earn the carta di soggiorno? I would really love to ask my wife about this in details but it seems like she has no idea about this at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

One could drive over Austria. There are no controls between Italy and Austria and Austria and Germany. Only if they are looking for a criminal or something like that :)

Comment: can you tell it to me in more details?

Comment: @Jinlee well between Italy Austria and Germany is no border control because of the schengen agreement. So unless they stop you for some reason like they look for a criminal or something you can just drive through the country. That's the great thing about the eu :) of course if you drive through Switzerland they will control you because Switzerland closed its borders

Comment: really? thank you for the infomation. i might as well take a train to austria and germany then.
one more question please.
Will I have any problem leaving italy with an train in eu?
since am asian it feels like i will be checked quite often.